# guild wars 2 beta client same as the real client

Tags: guild-wars-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to download the client again?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80719/do-i-need-to-download-the-client-again)

I have been playing GW2 in the beta. I have the beta client downloaded and it is up to date.

Do i need a different client to play the real game when it releases tomorrow, or is the beta client the same as the real client?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to download again.

This [Guild Wars 2 Launch](http://en.support.guildwars2.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9179/~/guild-wars-2-launch) page says:

> **Can I download the Guild Wars 2 client early?**
>
> If you’ve registered
>   your pre-purchase or pre-order and created your Guild Wars account,
>   you can go to [account management](https://account.guildwars2.com/login) today and download the client. Be
>   sure to update the client periodically to minimize your download at
>   launch.

Which I take to mean that the beta client we have installed, with updates, will be the client we need for the live launch.